# How to create popup window?

Tags: java, android, windows, popup

I created one media player, its working fine. I wish to create one popup window in the media player bottom....I am searching some sample code in google but i am really confused...any one give me the idea and also some sample link.......

```
Element description:

1. The copyright, disclaimer and buy block, this block contains links to popup
   windows that contain a copyright and or disclaimer. And an option to buy the
   application for the advertisement less version. The content of this block is fed trough
   the application XML feed. The color of the text is fed by the application xml plus the
   popup links and texts itself;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this;
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/06/custom-alertdialog.html

**EDIT:**
Sorry due to restriction in my network, I couldn't able to add comments, so I am editing my answer.

What you are saying a popup widow, in Android it is  Known as **Dialog**, which stays on the screen until user interacts with it

If you don't want user input for that then you can choose **Toast**, which stays specified time on the screen and disappears automatically

**Study this link keenly, your confusion will come to an end:**
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Just a link isn't a good answer. Please provide at least a summary.

Comment: can you please explain popup window? why we are using for our projects. I am confused...please

Comment: This link fully confused to me...... please provide another link are give me a simple coding.........

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `JDialog` or `JOptionPane`. Here is an example of how you can use `JOptionPane`:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
// Add whatever you want to the panel
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();
JButton btnAdd = new JButton("OK");
JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
Object[] options = {btnAdd, btnCancel};
pane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "The Title", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, null);
```